# why does appium open data:; in browser before the actual url

Tags: appium, appium-android, browser-automation

I am trying to use appium for android browser automation and my tests are passing, however I see that before it opens the actual URL , it goes to `data:;` before that. Can anyone help me understand why this happens? What is appium trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

The 'data:,' URL is just the default address that is navigated to when the browser is launched. You say that your tests pass so you must already be giving the URL you want to go to and continue with your tests.